# Do the "Soldiers of the Sea" in "Return of the Obra Dinn" have any basis in prior works?

Tags: return-of-the-obra-dinn

In chapter 6 of *Return of the Obra Dinn*, the ship is

> boarded by horrific crab creatures ridden by demonic, cloaked figures full of spikes.

Have these things or anything like them ever been seen before? Is there another name for them, or have they appeared in any mythology or prior sea-based fantasy horror works?

Comment: "*Unlike the other two beasts, the crab-riders are seemingly not based off of any existing or established nautical lore.*" - http://obradinn.wikia.com/wiki/Beasts